# java.lang.IllegalStateException: stream has already been operated upon or closed in junit

Tags: spring, junit, mockito

I am new for Mockito and i am trying throw NullPoinerException() when list is null and for this scenario i used below code for testing but i am getting exception **java.lang.IllegalStateException: stream has already been operated upon or closed**

### original

```
public List<Employee>getEmployeesListStartWithA(){

        List<Employee>list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(new Employee(1, "ram", "ram@gmail.com"));
        list.add(new Employee(2, "santhosh", "santhosh@gmail.com"));
        list.add(new Employee(3, "rita", "rita@gmail.com"));
        list.add(new Employee(4, "ramesh", "ramesh@gmail.com"));
        Stream<Employee>filterList = list.stream().filter(item->{
            return item.getName().startsWith("r");
        });

        if(filterList==null || filterList.collect(Collectors.toList()).size()==0){
           throw new NullPointerException();
        }

        return filterList.collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
```

### test:

```
@Test
public void getEmployeesListStartWithATest(){
    List<Employee>list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(new Employee(1, "ram", "ram@gmail.com"));
    list.add(new Employee(3, "rita", "rita@gmail.com"));
    list.add(new Employee(4, "ramesh", "ramesh@gmail.com"));
doReturn(null).when(configurationClass).getEmployeesListStartWithA();
    doThrow(new NullPointerException()).when(configurationClass).getEmployeesListStartWithA();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error comes from you're method and is unrelated to the test.

While `filterList` is a `stream` its closed once the filter operation has terminated.
 
Later doing the collect on it won't work.

You can fix the method by changing it to this:

```
public List<Employee> getEmployeesListStartWithA() {

    List<Employee>list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(new Employee(1, "ram", "ram@gmail.com"));
    list.add(new Employee(2, "santhosh", "santhosh@gmail.com"));
    list.add(new Employee(3, "rita", "rita@gmail.com"));
    list.add(new Employee(4, "ramesh", "ramesh@gmail.com"));
    List<Employee>filterList = list.stream().filter(item->{
        return item.getName().startsWith("r");
    }).collect(Collectors.toList());

    if(filterList==null || filterList.size()==0){
       throw new NullPointerException();
    }

    return filterList;
}
```

Also I suggest you do not throw a `NullPointerException`. That is just bad style, use a more proper exception instead (or simply return an empty list).

Comment: Also I suggest you do not throw a NullPointerException. That is just bad style, use a more proper exception instead (or simply return an empty list).--->So what is proper way can you please guide me?

Comment: how can i write test case for above method can you please explain me

Comment: The return of an empty list would be the most proper thing to do. You should only test against the desired output. From reading your test code I was not sure whether you want to test this method or if you want to mock this method (when it is used by another class)?

Comment: can you please paste some code then it may useful to me

Comment: Your `original` lookl like a hardcoded example to me, that is not really the code you are going to test, or? For a `real-world` method I would assume that `list` is actually a parameter as well as the starting letter? -- As long as I do not know what you are actually trying to do, that is not possible, You could open a chat room and we continue the discussion there?

Comment: yes actually i hard coded my original bacause just for practice

Comment: k. In either case there is no real need to do mocking here. You want to test that the result you get is correct (based on your input / or the hardcoded values),

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198665/discussion-between-krish-and-second).